# How to set an animation before starting the first activity?

Tags: android, animation

I'd like to know how to set a loading animation before the first activity starts. Currently, when my first activity begins there is a black screen, I'd like to replace it by an animation. Is that possible to do that ?

Comment: what do u mean by saying "loading animation"?

Comment: I want a splash screen (I didn't know that term).

Comment: Check my answer, and follow link for any help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want to add a logo splash is good way. Check this out, Its a `SplashScreen` activity which will be visible for 3 secs, and then will enter your main screen. More [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)

```
    public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    // Splash screen timer
    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
        }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok good ! I will try that and give you a feedback later. Thanks !

Comment: This is bad practice, use `windowBackground` instead: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time#themed

Comment: @Philio, As you can see this answer is pretty old from '16 and I believe this answer is correct according to time when it was asked. Kindly do not downvote.

Answer (score 1):

If black screen is your problem, try to make the activity as transparent. Refer this link:
[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)

If you want to animation activity transition, use the follow:

```
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.enter_anim, R.anim.exit_anim);
```

Where, enter_anim and exit_anim are animations defined in XML